# How to find manager of department

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm working with Active Directory currently.  I am able to pull a list of everyone who works in a department, but I am not sure how to tell which one is the manager.

```
public void MemberOf(string department)
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.server.com");

            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

            ds.Filter = ("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(department=" + department + "))");
            ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

            foreach (SearchResult temp in ds.FindAll())
            {
                string test1 = temp.Path;
            }
        }
```

This will return a list of people one of them being the manager the rest being direct reports to the manager.

Comment: How can you tell? Is the manager's `Manager` property empty? Or does the manager have some other, distinguishing property value? Does the manager e.g. belong to a specific group that his employee don't belong to?

Comment: I'm not sure that's part of the problems.  ManagerA has his own manager.  The employees then list ManagerA as their manager.  There has to be a simple way to see who manages a department I would think. @marc_s

Comment: Well, the problem is: the *department* as such (the `OU` container) doesn't have a manager property. Most likely, there would be something like a "manager" group or something that you could check for - that would be the easiest way to find these manager reliably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the best implementation, but without knowing what you want to use it for...how you're going to be getting the data...etc etc this is a quick and dirty implementation:

```
private void Test(string department)
    {
        //Create a dictionary using the manager as the key, employees for the values
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server.server.com");
        DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);

        ds.Filter = String.Format(("(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(department={0}))"), department);
        ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        foreach (SearchResult temp in ds.FindAll())
        {
            Employee e = new Employee();

            e.Manager = temp.Properties["Manager"][0].ToString();
            e.UserId = temp.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();
            e.Name = temp.Properties["displayName"][0].ToString();

            employees.Add(e);
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Manager { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped me get to where I needed to be. :)

Comment: Still need to figure out how to tell who manages a department, but this did help me get past something else I was stuck on.